# Запятая на стыке двух союзов (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение

Поставила запятую после «и», перед «если» (см. фото).
Подскажите, является ли это ошибкой? И если да, то грубая от она?

*И, если какое-то произведение искусства действительно гениально, то оно останется в мировой культуре навсегда.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Запятая перед "если" не нужна:
***И если** какое-то произведение искусства действительно гениально, **то** оно останется в мировой культуре навсегда.*

При «встрече» двух союзов запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие или перестановка придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза **то**, **так** или **но**, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и **не ставится**, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть двойного союза.

Другими словами, если после первого союза (**и**) следует сложносоставной союз ([**если... то**](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1191)), то запятая на стыке союзов не ставится.
*Холодной ночью… мальчик стучал в незнакомые дома, выспрашивая, где живёт Ознобишин, **и если ему не отвечало мёртвое молчание,** то раздавался бранчливый окрик либо подозрительный опрос* (К. Федин)

Сравните: *И то оно останется в мировой культуре навсегда* (изъятие или перестановка придаточного предложения невозможна).
Постановка "лишней" запятой относится к пунктуационным ошибкам. Думаю, что
такая ошибка не является грубой.
А вот отсутствие запятой перед соотносительным словом "то" являлось бы грубой ошибкой, так как перед "то" запятая ставится всегда.

**И если** верить общей теории относительности, **то** тут, в сильных полях тяготения, нас ждёт масса удивительных явлений... [Владилен Барашенков. Верен ли закон Ньютона? // «Знание — сила», 2003]

[Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140)